# 配列から重複取り出しを防ぐ

Tags: php, array

度々質問すみません。早急に教えて頂ければ幸いです。
二人のプレイヤーがカードを以下の通り引いた時、同じカードが重複して表示される現象を回避する方法をご教示頂けますでしょうか。

```
public function createCards()
{
    //変数の初期化
    $newCard = array();
    $marks = array(
        "clubs",
        "hearts",
        "diams",   
        "spades",
    );
    //山札を作成
    $card = array();
    for($mark = 0; $mark < 4; $mark++) {
        for($num = 1; $num <= 13; $num++) {    
            $newCard["mark"] = $marks[$mark];
            $newCard["number"] = $num;
            array_push($card,$newCard);
        }
    }
    return $card;
}

/**
 * 手札の作成
 * @param Array $tehuda_player1, $tehuda_player2
 * @return string
 */
public function shuffleCards($card)
{
    //山札をランダムに取り出す
    shuffle($card); 
    //各プレイヤー山札から5枚引く
    $tehuda_player1[] = array();
    $tehuda_player2[] = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $tehuda_player1[] = array_pop($card);
    }
    for($i = 0;$i < 5; $i++){
        $tehuda_player2[] = array_pop($card);
    }
    return $tehuda_player1;
    return $tehuda_player2;
}

/**
 * 手札の表示
 * 
 */ 
public function showCards($tehuda_player1,$tehuda_player2)
{
    //トランプの画像を用意する
    foreach($tehuda_player1 as $tmp) {
        $mark = $tmp["mark"];
        $number = $tmp["number"];
        echo '<img src="image/gif/'.$mark."_".$number.'.gif" alt = "">';
    }
}
```

理想としては、$tehuda_player1の処理が終わった後には$tehuda_player1が引いた分のカードが配列から無くなる事なのですが、$card-$tehuda_player1と書くと何も表示されなくなります。

原因わかる方、教えていただけたら幸いです。

---

コメントより、関数の使用想定を記載します。

```
$card = $trump->createCards(); //カード52枚 
$tehuda_player1 = $trump->shuffleCards($card); 
$tehuda_player2 = $trump->shuffleCards($card); 
$player1 = $trump->showCards($tehuda_player1); 
$player2 = $trump->showCards($tehuda_player2); 
echo "<div class='player1_cards'>".$player1."</div>"; 
echo "<div class='player2_cards'>".$player2."</div>";
```

Comment: `public function shuffleCards($card)`で`return`を2回繰り返しているのは故意ですか？1回目の`return`で`$tehuda_player1`を返した段階で`function`が終了するので`$tehuda_player2`が返らないと思うのですが？

Comment: $tehuda_player1と$tehuda_player2を両方返したかったのですが、returnの値を複数指定できませんでしたので、returnを2回書きましたが、初めの方しか機能しないのですね、、知りませんでした。

Comment: やるなら、`array($tehuda_player1,$tehuda_player2)`でひとつにまとめて返しては如何でしょうか？関数を使用している箇所が見当たらないので、どう言った使い方を想定しているか、どういった意図があるのか分からないですが……

Comment: $card = $trump->createCards(); //カード52枚
 $tehuda_player1 = $trump->shuffleCards($card);
  $tehuda_player2 = $trump->shuffleCards($card);
  $player1 = $trump->showCards($tehuda_player1);
  $player2 = $trump->showCards($tehuda_player2);
 
  echo "<div class='player1_cards'>".$player1."</div>";
  echo "<div class='player2_cards'>".$player2."</div>";

Comment: 回答を追記しました。また、追加情報はコメントではなく質問文を編集して追記を知らせましょう。

Comment: 質問文を編集しました。間違っていれば修正ください。

Comment: 此方は解決したのでしょうか？使用想定から見て解釈に問題があるので、私の回答の追記をご覧ください。

Comment: 1つ目として、まず回答で返信しないでください。2つ目、私の回答に全文を追加しましたが、全コピペして自分と相手の手札が被りますか？3つ目、問題が継続する場合、まだ問題が発生しているコードを質問文に記載ください。4つ目、解決した場合は解決した回答を承認、または自分で解決した内容を回答し承認してください。

Answer (score 1):

しばらくPHP触ってなかったので誤字あるかもですが、適当に使ってみました。
使っている想定が分からないので既出の関数はいじっていませんが、
先ほどのコメントで言った返却部分のみいじってまとめてます。
クラス名も何つけてるのかわからないので適当に`fooClass`です。
最後の出力関数でPlayer1しか表示していないのが気になりますが……適度にいじって下さい。
**追記**
おかしな箇所もう1つありました。
`shuffleCards`内で配列を初期化している際に
`$val[] = array()`になっていますが、間違いです。
`$val = array()`です。`$val[]`は**既に配列の変数の末尾**に追加します。

```
public function createCards()
{
    //変数の初期化
    $newCard = array();
    $marks = array(
        "clubs",
        "hearts",
        "diams",   
        "spades",
    );
    //山札を作成
    $card = array();
    for($mark = 0; $mark < 4; $mark++) {
        for($num = 1; $num <= 13; $num++) {    
            $newCard["mark"] = $marks[$mark];
            $newCard["number"] = $num;
            array_push($card,$newCard);
        }
    }
    return $card;
}

/**
 * 手札の作成
 * @param Array $tehuda_player1, $tehuda_player2
 * @return array
 */
public function shuffleCards($card)
{
    //山札をランダムに取り出す
    shuffle($card); 
    //各プレイヤー山札から5枚引く
    $tehuda_player1 = array();
    $tehuda_player2 = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $tehuda_player1[] = array_pop($card);
    }
    for($i = 0;$i < 5; $i++){
        $tehuda_player2[] = array_pop($card);
    }
    return array($tehuda_player1,$tehuda_player2);
}

/**
 * 手札の表示
 * 
 */ 
public function showCards($tehuda_player1,$tehuda_player2)
{
    //トランプの画像を用意する
    foreach($tehuda_player1 as $tmp) {
        $mark = $tmp["mark"];
        $number = $tmp["number"];
        echo '<img src="image/gif/'.$mark."_".$number.'.gif" alt = "">';
    }
}

/**
 * 使用用途が分からないので使ってみる
 */
public function initialize(){
    $baseCards = $this->createCards();
    $playerCards = $this->shuffleCards($baseCards);
    $this->showCards($playerCards[0],$playerCards[1]);
}

$clsObj = new fooClass();
$clsObj->initialize();
```

---

**質問文追記により、更に追記**
関数内で`echo`していますが、`echo`は即時に出力されるので、
現在のままですとカードのイメージが出力された後に`div`画出力されます。
※上記の修正済みの関数での実行を想定するように修正しました。

```
$card = $trump->createCards(); //カード52枚 
$tehuda_players = $trump->shuffleCards($card);
//player1出力
echo "<div class='player1_cards'>";
$trump->showCards($tehuda_players[0]); 
echo "</div>"; 
//player2出力
echo "<div class='player2_cards'>"; 
$trump->showCards($tehuda_players[1]); 
echo "</div>";
```

---

**追記**
試験用にコード全文を再記します。
私の上記の回答をほとんどそのままですが、
下記のコードをコピペして重複しますか？
(`showCards`の引数を1つにし、出力が分かりやすいように改行を入れています。)

```
<?php
Class fooClass{
    public function createCards()
    {
        //変数の初期化
        $newCard = array();
        $marks = array(
            "clubs",
            "hearts",
            "diams",   
            "spades",
        );
        //山札を作成
        $card = array();
        for($mark = 0; $mark < 4; $mark++) {
            for($num = 1; $num <= 13; $num++) {    
                $newCard["mark"] = $marks[$mark];
                $newCard["number"] = $num;
                array_push($card,$newCard);
            }
        }
        return $card;
    }

    /**
     * 手札の作成
     * @param Array $tehuda_player1, $tehuda_player2
     * @return array
     */
    public function shuffleCards($card)
    {
        //山札をランダムに取り出す
        shuffle($card); 
        //各プレイヤー山札から5枚引く
        $tehuda_player1 = array();
        $tehuda_player2 = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $tehuda_player1[] = array_pop($card);
        }
        for($i = 0;$i < 5; $i++){
            $tehuda_player2[] = array_pop($card);
        }
        return array($tehuda_player1,$tehuda_player2);
    }

    /**
     * 手札の表示
     * 
     */ 
    public function showCards($tehuda_player)
    {
        //トランプの画像を用意する
        foreach($tehuda_player as $tmp) {
            $mark = $tmp["mark"];
            $number = $tmp["number"];
            echo '<img src="image/gif/'.$mark."_".$number.'.gif" alt = "">'."\n";
        }
    }
}

$trump= new fooClass();
$card = $trump->createCards(); //カード52枚 
$tehuda_players = $trump->shuffleCards($card);
//player1出力
echo "<div class='player1_cards'>\n";
$trump->showCards($tehuda_players[0]); 
echo "</div>\n\n"; 
//player2出力
echo "<div class='player2_cards'>\n"; 
$trump->showCards($tehuda_players[1]); 
echo "</div>"; 
?>
```