# phpの値にcssを反映したい

Tags: php, css

phpで変数が入った値にcssを反映させ、変数に入った画像ファイルの出力位置を変更したいのですが、なぜか以下コードでは反映されません。
どなたか、アドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

上記変数の中には5枚のトランプの画像が格納されています。
以下は、phpのコードです。

```
 "<div class='player1_cards'>".$player1."</div>";
 "<div class='player2_cards'>".$player2."</div>";


<css>
.player1_cards{
    background:#fff888;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:20%;
}
```

これで、カードの出力位置を直そうと思っても、全く反映されないのですが、なぜなのでしょうか。
お手数ですが、教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

まず[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27841/)が解決しているのかどうかが不明ですが、
記載しているコードには特に問題はありません。
あえて言うのであれば`<css>`が気になる程度です。
(単に質問する際にcssというラベルをつけているだけかと思いますが…勿論`<style>`ですよね？)
前回の質問のコードを実行した際の出力結果にCSSを当てると下記のようになります。

```css
.player1_cards{
    background:#fff888;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:20%;
}

.player2_cards{
    background:#fff888;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class='player1_cards'>
  <img src="image/gif/spades_4.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/hearts_1.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/spades_9.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/clubs_9.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/clubs_6.gif" alt = "">
</div>

<div class='player2_cards'>
  <img src="image/gif/clubs_11.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/diams_12.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/diams_13.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/hearts_7.gif" alt = "">
  <img src="image/gif/hearts_10.gif" alt = "">
</div>
```

まずは前回の質問を解決させ、結果が正しく出力されたことを確認してください。